# RDRStickyKeyboard disables other UI

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need an iMessage Type Keyboard where a TextView sits above keyboard, I found this `RDRStickyKeyboard` but I have been troubled using this iOS Library.

What I did was simply add this code

```
keyboardView = [[RDRStickyKeyboardView alloc] initWithScrollView:tableViewPost];
keyboardView.frame = self.view.bounds;
keyboardView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[keyboardView.inputView.rightButton addTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(didTapSend:)
                             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:keyboardView];
```

The keyboard works fine, but I can't seem to interact with the rest of the app for example I have a navigation button to switch to another view but the navigation buttons don't work. If I remove the keyboard everything works fine.

Why can I not interact with the other tap gestures when I add this `RDRStickyKeyboardView`?

Has anyone used this?

Comment: Did you review this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)?